# Celery on Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Dash program that requires data to be collected in real-time from a separate monitor. Flask seems to lock out other functions so currently I'm running two separate programs. I would like to experiment with Celery and RabbitMQ but I've hit an early road block, real early.

I've Brew installed RabbitMQ. The documentation talks about

"After you’ve installed RabbitMQ with brew you need to add the following to your path to be able to start and stop the broker: add it to the start-up file for your shell (e.g., .bash_profile or .profile).

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"

I'm confused as to how to do this. I running my program on MacOS Catalina, using PyCharm. I have looked everywhere for a .Bash.profile file but cannot find it anywhere. I know I'm missing some basic knowledge here. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you

I apologize for the basic question but I'm really lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't run it on MacOS, but the instructions are different from what you said: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-homebrew.html

Comment: Also, why not dockerize? It's cleaner and more reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I only have limited experience with docker. Do you recommend I dockerize each app in separate containers? So that they don't interphere with each other? Thx

Comment: That's exactly the point